# Auto renew of thumbprint in an ASP.NET MVC Application which uses Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have configured Azure AD (Microsoft Entra ID) authentication in an ASP.NET MVC project using WS-Federation. For that, I am getting a thumbprint from the Azure App, storing that into the `web.config` file.

Authentication has been working perfectly fine since last year. Still, the problem is that after every few months the thumbprint expires, I have to get the new thumbprint from the Azure Portal and replace it in the `web.config` file.

I am wondering if there is a way to automate this process or a better way of not manually updating the thumbprint after every couple of months.

`web.config` content for a reference:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="api://1233d47f-63a3-47KP-97b9-83225b1daXYA" />
        </audienceUris>
        <federatedAuthentication>
            <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://login.microsoftonline.com/asdfghjk-50c5-44e9-a5a3-ff1cdf3227e5/wsfed" realm="api://1233d47f-63a3-47KP-97b9-83225b1daXYA" requireHttps="true" />
            <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
        </federatedAuthentication>
        <applicationService>
            <claimTypeRequired>
                <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
                <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
            </claimTypeRequired>
        </applicationService>
        <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
        <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <trustedIssuers>
                <add thumbprint="ASDF1234d2d3bf259183107febbeaef25678GHJK" name="https://sts.windows.net/1233d47f-63a3-47KP-97b9-83225b1daXYA/" />
            </trustedIssuers>
        </issuerNameRegistry>
    </service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the thumbprint directly from Azure and set that during *Application_AuthenticateRequest*. Following were the code changes in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /// Due to the way the ASP.Net pipeline works, the only way to change 
            /// configurations inside federatedAuthentication (which are configurations on the http modules)
            /// is to catch another event, which is raised everytime a request comes in.
            ConfigureWSFederation();

            ...
        }


private static void ConfigureWSFederation()
        {
            // Load the federatedAuthentication settings
            WSFederationAuthenticationModule federatedModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule as WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
            if (federatedModule?.ServiceConfiguration != null)
            {
                #region Get Thumbprint from the Azure App Registration directly and and use that for WS Fed authentication, ignore the thumbprint from web.config file

                //replace issuer(https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/wsfed) to get the meta address(https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml)
                var metadataAddress = federatedModule.Issuer.Replace("wsfed", "FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml");
                var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<WsFederationConfiguration>(
                    metadataAddress,
                    new WsFederationConfigurationRetriever(),
                    new HttpDocumentRetriever { RequireHttps = true });
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                var wsFedConfig = configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

                // Access the thumbprint from wsFedConfig object
                var thumbprint = wsFedConfig.SigningKeys.FirstOrDefault()?.KeyId;

                // Update the thumbprint in the web.config
                if (thumbprint != null)
                {
                    var issuer = ((Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry)federatedModule?.ServiceConfiguration?.IssuerNameRegistry).ConfiguredTrustedIssuers;
                    if (issuer != null)
                    {
                        var oldIssuer = issuer.First();
                        if (oldIssuer.Key != thumbprint.ToString())//UPDATE THMUBPRINT ONLY IF THEY ARE DIFFERENT
                        {
                            issuer.Remove(oldIssuer);
                            var newValue = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(thumbprint.ToString(), oldIssuer.Value);
                            issuer.Add(newValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Unable to configure the federated module. The modules weren't loaded.");
            }
        }
```